# List all categories but exclude current post category on single post page

Tags: php, categories, terms

I want to display a list of categories excluding the category of the current single post that the user is navigating on. The list is displayed on the `single.php` template.

I'm using this code to display all categories and is working well but I can't find a way to exclude the current post category:

```
<ul class="submenu-category">
  <?php
    // your taxonomy name
    $tax = 'category';

    // get the terms of taxonomy
    $terms = get_terms( $tax, $args = array(
      'hide_empty' => false, // do not hide empty terms
    ));

    // loop through all terms
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {

        // Get the term link
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

        if( $term->count > 0 )
          // display link to term archive
          // echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name .'</a>';
          echo '<li><a data-filter=".'. $term->slug .'" href="javascript:void(0)" >' . $term->name .'</a></li>';

        elseif( $term->count !== 0 )
          // display name
          echo '' . $term->name .'';
    } ?>
</ul>
```

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here would be to use the queried object's ID to get the post terms (*because we are most probably outside the loop here, if inside the loop, just use `get_the_ID()`*). From there, we can use `wp_list_pluck()` to get all the term ID's and simply pass that to `get_terms()` `exclude` parameter

Just a note, as from WordPress V4.5, the taxonomy should be passed as an arguments of `$args`, I'll handle both cases

### PRE 4.5

```
// Set all our variables
$taxonomy = 'category';
$post_id  = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object_id();
$args     = [
    'hide_empty' => false
];

// Get the ID's from the post terms
$post_terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
if (    $post_terms
     && !is_wp_error( $post_terms )
) {
    $term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $post_terms, 'term_id' );

    // Get all the terms with the post terms excluded
    $args['exclude'] = $term_ids;
}

$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
```

### V 4.5 + version

```
// Set all our variables
$taxonomy = 'category';
$post_id  = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object_id();
$args     = [
    'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => false
];

// Get the ID's from the post terms
$post_terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
if (    $post_terms
     && !is_wp_error( $post_terms )
) {
    $term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $post_terms, 'term_id' );

    // Get all the terms with the post terms excluded
    $args['exclude'] = $term_ids;
}

$terms = get_terms( $args );
```

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. It did the job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you will need an array that contains all categories of the current post:

```
$current_cats = wp_get_post_categories(); // assuming you are in the loop
```

Then you have to loop through $current_cats and remove the items from $terms

```
    foreach( $current_cats as $cat ) {
        if (($key = array_search($cat, $terms)) !== false) {
            unset($terms[$key]);
            }
        }
```

Hopefully that works.

Comment: You can do this much faster. Note, you do not want to use `wp_get_post_categories()` as it makes an extra db call

Comment: You mean explode `get_the_category_list (', ')`  and then strip the tags, or something else?

Comment: See my answer, I explained it there

Comment: Sorry, i just clicked the link to your comment and didn't see you had added an answer. Yours is definitely smarter, but less easy to understand for beginning WP programmers, I think.