# How to list all categories a post is in, but exclude current post´s category on single post page

Tags: categories

I´d like to list all categories (links) a post is in, like when I use "the_category()", but need to exclude the current category.

Ex: Post name is "Bob Marley´s songs", published in the categories "Bob marley", "Reggae Songs" and "Best Songs Ever".
When I´m inside a category, I wnat to show only the other two categories links.

Anyboby?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226483/list-all-categories-but-exclude-current-post-category-on-single-post-page) by Peter Goosen for the same question.

Comment: Already tried it, but does notthing (loads notinhg). Maybe i´m using it wrong. Inserted it in single.php but does not work.